# How to select to the next bookmark in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to select the text between the current cursor position and the next/previous bookmark in SublimeText3?

Combinations with the <kbd>shift</kbd> key don't work: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> goes to the previous bookmark (that's <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> = "go to the next bookmark"). Holding <kbd>shift</kbd> while selecting the "next bookmark" menu item doesn't work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to do that, you'll probablly need a plugin. I have just made this simple plugin that selects from the current cursor position to the next/previous bookmark depending on the value of the forward argument.

This is the plugin:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SelectToBookmarkCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **args):
        """Get initial position"""
        initialPoint = self.view.sel()[0].begin()

        """Clear selected things (if any)"""
        self.view.sel().clear()

        """Move to next bookmark or previous bookmark"""
        forward = args.get('forward','true')
        if forward is True:
            self.view.run_command("next_bookmark")
        else:
            self.view.run_command("prev_bookmark")


        """Get current position (position of the bookmark)"""
        finalPoint = self.view.sel()[0].begin()

        """Clear selected things (if any)"""
        self.view.sel().clear()

        """Region to select"""
        regionToSelect = sublime.Region(initialPoint, finalPoint)

        """Add the region to the selection"""
        self.view.sel().add(regionToSelect)
```

Use *Tools > New Plugin* and use the provided plugin. Save it as *SelectToBookmark.py* .
Finally, add the keyBindings to your user file using something like this:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+e"],
    "command": "select_to_bookmark",
    "args": {"forward": true}
}
```

Use another keyBinding with *forward* argument set to *false* to select from the current position to the previous bookmark.

Edit: As user @MattDMo has commented:
"make sure you save the .py file in *Packages/**User*** - you can locate the directory on your system (if it doesn't come up automatically) by selecting the *Preferences -> Browse Packages*... menu option"

Comment: just a note - make sure you save the `.py` file in `Packages/User` - you can locate the directory on your system (if it doesn't come up automatically) by selecting the ***`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`*** menu option.

Comment: Works a treat! Thx! In OS-X 10.8.5, `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` opens a finder window with the `Packages` folder selected. You can `command-C` in finder, then paste in the "Save As" dialogue of sublime text to get to the packages folder (and then select `User` to save it in there). I used "ctrl+alt+f2" and "ctrl+alt+shift+f2" key bindings to be similar to other bookmark keybindings.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Thank you @MattDMo, I have updated the answer with that info.

Comment: It would be great if this script can also support [SublimeBookmark](https://github.com/bollu/sublimeBookmark) package.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @sergioFC's answer. This version is used for the [SublimeBookmark](https://github.com/bollu/sublimeBookmark) package.

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SelectToBookmarkCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **args):
        """Get initial position"""
        initialPoint = self.view.sel()[0].begin()

        """Clear selected things (if any)"""
        self.view.sel().clear()

        """Move to next bookmark or previous bookmark"""
        forward = args.get('forward','true')
        if forward is True:
            self.view.window().run_command("sublime_bookmark",{ "type" : "goto_previous" })
        else:
            self.view.window().run_command("sublime_bookmark",{ "type" : "goto_next" })


        """Get current position (position of the bookmark)"""
        finalPoint = self.view.sel()[0].begin()

        """Clear selected things (if any)"""
        self.view.sel().clear()

        """Region to select"""
        regionToSelect = sublime.Region(initialPoint, finalPoint)

        """Add the region to the selection"""
        self.view.sel().add(regionToSelect)
```